# ¿Otra forma de armar esta lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo que armar una lista con letras que contenga 'fichas'. En este caso serian 16 fichas y la hice de una manera media rudimentaria

```
def generador_fichas():

    fichas = ["D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D",
          "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s"]

    return fichas
```

El problema es que seguramente mas adelante las cantidad de fichas van a ser elegibles por las que uno desee, mi duda es: hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin que quede tan feo?
Por ejemplo:
Si uno quiere 8 fichas hay alguna manera de iterarlas y crearlas pasándole el numero y las letras que quiero que contenga? (Por ejemplo: 8 fichas con "D" y "s" )

Gracias

Comment: Sip, `fichas = ["D"]*8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A ver si te parece más bonito:**

```
def generador_fichas(n, lista):
    return [f  for f in lista for _ in range(n)]

fichas = ['D', 'S']
n_fichas = 8

print(generador_fichas(n_fichas, fichas))
```

A la función le envías los tipos de fichas en una lista y el número de repeticiones de cada una.

Con dos ciclos for vas añadiendo a una nueva lista todas las fichas

**Imprime**

```
['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```

**Comprension de listas**

La comprensión de lista es una forma de escribir un ciclo `for` pero de forma más compacta y rápida, puedes leer más en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

la estructura completa es `[dato for dato in iterable condicion]`

El código equivalente sería:

```
def generador_fichas(n, lista):
    resultado = []  #  Creas una nueva lista vacía
    for f in lista: #  Recorres la lista con las fichas
        for i in range(n):  #  número de fichas
            resultado.append(f)  #  Añades la nueva ficha a la lista.
    return resultado
```

Comment: Sería bueno que expliques la sintaxis de comprensión de lista ya que creo que el OP no sabe mucho de python y lo único que hará es copiar y pegar el código sin entender nada. Además que usas una comprensión de lista anidada

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer una función que reciba como parámetro las letras y el número de fichas, luego usando la sintaxis `["x"]*n` para generar una lista de n elementos repetidos generamos la lista de fichas

```py
def generar_fichas(num, letras):
    fichas = []
    for letra in letras:
        fichas.extend([letra]*num)
    return fichas
```

Ahora puedes hacer

```py
fichas = generar_fichas(8,["D","d"])
print(fichas)
```